# Symfony 2.2 - Generate URL from route OR simply display URL

Tags: php, symfony, routes, twig, symfony-2.2

I'm developing a navigation system for Symfony 2. It's working really nicely so far. So far, there is a config file like so:

```
# The menu name ...
primary:
    # An item in the menu ...
    Home:
        enabled: 1
        # Routes where the menu item should be shown as 'active' ...
        routes:
            - "a_route_name"
        # Where the link goes to ... the problem ...
        target: "a_route_name"
```

This layout is working nicely, and the menu works. Apart from in my template, I can only generate links using the target value that correspond to routes within an application; i.e, not an external URL.

The template is as follows for generating the navigation:

```
{# This is what puts the data for the menu into the page currently ... #}
{% set primary_nav = menu_data('primary') %}

<nav role="navigation" class="primary-nav">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        {% for key, item in primary_nav if item.enabled is defined and item.enabled %}
            {% if item.routes is defined and app.request.attributes.get('_route') in item.routes %}
                <li class="active">
            {% else %}
                <li>
            {% endif %}
                {% if item.target is defined %}
                    <a href="{{ path(item.target) }}">{{ key }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    {{ key }}
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Is there a simple way to allow the `path()` function or, something similar to generate URLs from routes, or just simply use a given URL if it validates as one?

I got as far as trying `url()`, and looked around the docs but couldn't see anything.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such twig extension, but you can easily create one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Twig extension that check if a route exists :

- if it exists, the corresponding generated url is returned
- else, the url (or other stuff) is returned without any change

In your services.yml, declare your twig extension and inject the router component.
Add the following lines and change namespaces :

```
  fuz_tools.twig.path_or_url_extension:
    class: 'Fuz\ToolsBundle\Twig\Extension\PathOrUrlExtension'
    arguments: ['@router']
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

Then create a Twig\Extension directory in your bundle, and create PathOrUrlExtension.php :

```
<?php

namespace Fuz\ToolsBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;

class PathOrUrlExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    private $_router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->_router = $router;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
                // will call $this->pathOrUrl if pathOrUrl() function is called from twig
                'pathOrUrl' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'pathOrUrl')
        );
    }

    public function pathOrUrl($pathOrUrl)
    {
        // the route collection returns null on undefined routes
        $exists = $this->_router->getRouteCollection()->get($pathOrUrl);
        if (null !== $exists)
        {
            return $this->_router->generate($pathOrUrl);
        }
        return $pathOrUrl;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "pathOrUrl";
    }

}
```

You can now use your new function :

```
{{ pathOrUrl('fuz_home_test') }}
<br/>
{{ pathOrUrl('http://www.google.com') }}
```

Will display :

[image]